# Locale aware bean validation message interpolation at ExceptionMapper in openliberty

Tags: jax-rs, bean-validation, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have a JAX-RS `@POST` endpoint whose input data has to be `@Valid`:

```java
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response myEndpoint(@javax.validation.Valid MyInputData input) { /*...*/ }
```

With `MyInputData` class annotated with many constraints:

```java
@lombok.Data
public class InputData {
  @Size(min = 1, max = 3)
  private String someString;

  /* ... */
}
```

Beyond that I have an `ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException>` that transform the Exception into a `Collection<String>` (basically every single `ConstraintViolation` transformed to `String` using its `getMesssage()` method), then returns a `Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(list).build()`.

Everything is working nicely. Fed an invalid input and I get back a HTTP 400 with a nice array of constraint violations in json format.

So far, so good...

BUT... the messages are in server's locale. Even if HTTP post sends a `Accept-language` header (and it is correctly detected when getting `HttpServletRequest::getLocale`).

By the time the `ExceptionMapper` gets hold of `ConstraintViolation` every message has already been interpolated, so no chance set the client locale.

Since the validation runs even before the JAX-RS resource (indeed, the JAX-RS resource isn't even called in case of invalid input), this locale aware message interpolator must be configured somewhere else.

Where? Is there already a `MessageInterpolator` implementation whose operation takes the `HttpServletRequest` locale into account?